# webpack extract css into separate file using extract-text-webpack-plugin

Tags: webpack, extract-text-plugin

i am trying to extract all `.css` into a separate file using webpack. To do this i am using `xtract-text-webpack-plugin`.

for some reason i am not getting any file out put after running web pack.

here is my webpack.config file

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');

const ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

const css = new ExtractTextPlugin('styles/[name].css');

module.exports = {
    entry: [
        './App/main.js'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, '/wwwroot/js/'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.css']
    },
    module: {
        rules: [{
            test: /\.css$/,
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                use: 'css-loader'
            })
        }]
    },
    plugins: [
        css
    ],

}
```

this is the output i get in console

```
Hash: 81acf65502ca13764b09
Version: webpack 3.2.0
Time: 71ms
  Asset     Size  Chunks             Chunk Names
main.js  2.62 kB       0  [emitted]  main
   [0] multi ./App/main.js 28 bytes {0} [built]
   [1] ./App/main.js 27 bytes {0} [built]
```

no `.css` file in my wwwroot folder. 
any idea why this is happening?

here is `package.json` file

```
"dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "css-loader": "^0.28.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack": "^3.2.0"
  }
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i was able to figure this out.

my webpack configuration was correct.

there are 2 ways of doing this

1st way you can require `.scss` and it will provide an entry point for css files.

2nd way you can create second entry point in your webpack

```
 entry: {
        index: "./scripts/index.js",
        vendor: "./styles/yourcss.css"
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways to do this. Here's the way that I have been doing....

```
module: {
            rules: [
                {
                    test: /\.css$/, use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract(
                        { use: isDevBuild ? 'css-loader' : 'css-loader?minimize' }
                    )
                }
        },
        output: { path: path.join(__dirname, clientBundleOutputDir) },
        plugins: [
            new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css')
```

All my CSS with this configuration, gets extracted into a single site.css file.

Comment: It seems like you are doing same thing i am. But I'm not getting any css files generated in output. Could this be webpack settings somewhere?

Comment: No. Can you try `new ExtractTextPlugin('site.css')` and see if that's working for you first?

Comment: I changed to your suggestion and no `.css` was generated. Only js files are been generated.

Comment: anyone else have any idea?

Comment: no there is no errors in console. maybe i have a wrong version of some package. here ill update question with versions in my `package.json` file